# Integrating html form with paypal

Tags: html, forms, paypal

I have created a `website` for the sale of custom Xbox controllers.
On the site I have `form` which you can select and customize different parts of the controller via `drop-down` lists, `radio-buttons` etc...

My question is the following:

`Is there some way in which I can link the information from the input methods discussed above to the PayPal button?`

I know I can go on the PayPal site and create `buttons` from there, and this will generate code for a `button` but this will not take information from the `input` methods above.

Thanks, sorry if this is confusing.

Comment: generally this site is for programming problems not conceptual answers based on an Idea. Please give it your best attempt and bring back what you have hacked together and we can help you work from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do the following:

**On your side:**
Develop a small Java web-service on *axis2*, which is very easy.
Connect your web-app to your service so that whenever the user selects and customizes different parts of the controller it will persist the output of controllers' specifications on the service side.

**On PayPal side:**
On the PayPal site create the buttons, and in the code under the buttons call your webservice to retrieve the data and do anything with it.